# differentiate between files and directories

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a file explorer in android. So in the list view i m showing all the folders and files, but currently all have same icon i.e of a folder. I want different icons for folder and directories. Moreover when i click on a file i want to see list of applications which can open it. Currently i m able to open a directory when clicked and when a file is clicked i show a toast unable to open.
Already thought about many thing but still unable to figure out
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
Here is my activity:

```
package com.rrawat.fileexplorer;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class ListFileActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_files);

        // Use the current directory as title
        path = "/sdcard";
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
            path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        }
        setTitle(path);

        // Read all files sorted into the values-array
        List values = new ArrayList();
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.canRead()) {
            setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
        }
        String[] list = dir.list();
        if (list != null) {
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
                    values.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(values);

        // Put the data into the list
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist,R.id.Itemname,values));
        /*ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);*/

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            filename = path + filename;
        } else {
            filename = path + File.separator + filename;
        }
        if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("path", filename);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My xmls:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

mylist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/folder" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom adapter and then override `getView()` as Bojan Kseneman said.

Right now, you are using the default implementation of `ArrayAdapter`, but you can create a class that `extends ArrayAdapter` and define it like:

```
public class FilesAndFoldersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public FilesAndFoldersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
       super(context, 0, values);
    } 

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position 
       String filePath = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view 
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
       } 

       // Lookup view for data population 
       TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
       ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object 
       tvName.setText(filePath);

       if (new File(filePath).isDirectory()) {
           ivImage.setImageResouce(R.drawable.folder_icon);
       } else {
           ivImage.setImageResouce(R.drawable.file_icon);
       }

       // Return the completed view to render on screen 
       return convertView;
   } 
}
```

The important part of this code to you, is the one that checks whether the file is a directory or file and then uses the corresponding icon on the ImageView.

After creating the custom adapter class, all you have to do is set it as your ListView's adapter like so:

```
setListAdapter(new FilesAndFoldersAdapter(this, values));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to determine if a File is a directory.

```
boolean isDir = new File(path).isDirectory();
```

Comment: but while inflating layout how can i keep seperate icons for both. any idea ?

Comment: in the onCreateView of recycler/listview check if it is a directory or not then set the icon according to the view holder